# problem with jtabbedpane in java

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

is it possible to  loading of tabs in jtabedpane dyanamically in java..

that means i have frame that consinting of one tabbedpane..

in that i have 10 tabs and in each tab  consting of another tabbedpane and in that each tabbedpane has 4 tabs and each tab consisting buttons and textfields......

when i login into my project  the next frame takes more time to visible....

this is happens why because i have more tabbedpanes in my frame so that it takes the lot's of time to visible..

my question is..

is it possible to load tabs content dynamically when i click the tab in tabbedpane.....

or is it possible to load tabbedpanes fastly......????????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be quick to load tab panes.  What must be taking a moment is the content in the tabs.  You can create tabs dynamically with the same way you create them when you build the GUI initially.  My guess is that the content is your real problem.  Depending on what that is you can load some items on threads other than the EDT and then come back.  (Look into SwingWorker).

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to push the creation of your inner tab panes to occur after initially displaying your tab pane..

1. Create the outer tab pane
2. Create stub panels for all tabs in the outer pane - this will put placeholders in for your tabs, making it look to the user that they have already been created.
3. Create content for the first tab.
4. Iterate over tabs 2 to *n*, creating `Runnable` instances that setup the content of the tabs, including their inner tab panes.  Use these `Runnable` instances as the param to `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`.  This will put these actions at the end of the EDT, so they will be performed after the current action has completed.
5. Complete the setup of your outer tab pane, adding it to your `JFrame` or other container and setting it visible.